# Boost multi_index_container, get index by tag results in compiler error

Tags: c++, templates, boost, gcc4

So, I'm trying to dabble with the `multi_index_container` and am having a rather strange compiler error, first here is the simplest example to demonstrate my problem (I'm probably missing something stupidly simple)...

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>

namespace multi_index = boost::multi_index;

template <typename _IdType>
class A
{
public:
  typedef _IdType IdType;
  IdType getId() const { return id; }

private:
  IdType id;
};

struct id_index{};

template <typename Traits>
class Container
{
  typedef typename Traits::AType AType;
  typedef typename AType::IdType IdType;

  typedef typename multi_index::multi_index_container<
    AType,
    multi_index::indexed_by<
      // sort by Id
      multi_index::ordered_non_unique<multi_index::tag<id_index>, BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_CONST_MEM_FUN(AType, IdType, getId) >
    >
  > ASet;

  typedef typename ASet::template index<id_index>::type::const_iterator a_it;
  typedef typename ASet::template index<id_index>::type::reverse_iterator a_rit;

  typedef typename ASet::template index<id_index>::type id_index_t;

public:

  bool addA(AType const& cA)
  {
    const id_index_t& os = _cSet.get<id_index>(); // line 1: errors occur here
    // .. do stuff
    return true;
  }

private:
  // Instance of the container...
  ASet _cSet;
};

struct ATraits
{
  typedef A<int> AType;
};

int main(void)
{
  Container<ATraits> container;

  ATraits::AType a;

  container.addA(a);

  return 0;
}
```

The errors reported by g++ (gcc 4.4.4, linux) is:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token (@ line 1)
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token (@ line 1)
```

So this was working fine till I converted the Container to a class template, after this, I get this error, and can't work out why..

Any ideas will be appreciated...

Comment: I really have no idea why is that happening, but VC2010 compiles the code fine!

Comment: @AraK, I guess this is a gcc odity, but the solution by @skwllsp works fine now!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  bool addA(AType const& cA)
  {
    const id_index_t& os = _cSet.template get<id_index>(); // line 1: errors occur here
    // .. do stuff
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: ARRGH... I thought it may be simple! This is template/typename hell... I actually gave up and used `get<id_index>(_cSet)`, but I think I'll revert back to this. thx!

Comment: @Nim: don't, free functions are the way to go :)

Comment: @Metthieu, really? But could it be that the member function could take advantage of some implementation detail that the free function may not be able to?